# How can i initilaze BluetoothConnectionService on Fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to try initilaze bluetoothservicejava on my fragment but i cant. 
(My connection sucesfull before the this fragment).
On my fragment i added this

```
BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
```

and added this:

```
mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(getActivity());
if(mBluetoothConnection!=null){
    Log.d(TAG,"initilazed mbluetoothconnection");
}
```

But i dont see any log my screen so i cant initilaze.